# Importing Access DB file in SAS but failing

Tags: import, sas

I am trying to run below code but failing with error 'ERROR: DBMS type ACCESS not valid for import.' Not sure what is the issue.

```
LIBNAME db 'C:\Extra';
PROC IMPORT DBMS=ACCESS
            OUT=WORK.Finished_IP
            DATATABLE='IP Input Data'
            REPLACE; 
            DATABASE= "db.Finished data.accdb";
   USEDATE=YES;
   SCANTIME=NO;
   DBSASLABEL=NONE;
RUN;
```

Comment: First off, I think your `DATABASE` specification is wrong (or at least something I've not seen before done that way); but that's not the error you're getting. Do you have `ACCESS to PC FILES` licensed?

Comment: Yes. Is there any other way to extract data from access in SAS?

Comment: If you have it licensed it should be a fine solution. Change DATABASE= to reflect the full path to the database rather than using a libname and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: I tried that but its still giving me same error.

Comment: is there any other way to extract data from access in SAS?

Comment: libname access (`libname db access 'c:\extra\finshed data.accdb';` then treat it like a SAS libname, which means use it in SET statement directly, `db.<table name>` as table).  But if you're not getting IMPORT to work then I wonder about that.  You also could use OLEDB if you have that licensed, or ODBC.

Comment: How can i use OLEDB in this case in SAS program??

Comment: Have you tried googling it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)" driver installed you can use this to create your libname directly to the database file like so:

```
libname Test ODBC noprompt="DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
                            DBQ=C:\local\Your_DB.accdb";
```

You can see if you have the driver under the ODBC Data Source Administrator found in Administration Tools in the Control Panel.

Using this method means that tables in the database can be read in like normal SAS datasets.